# Trying to get UIBinder to give me a span not a div

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am building a widget with UiBinder, and I need to have it enclosed in a `<span />` but UiBinder only gives me `<div />`. E.g. `<g:HTMLPanel />` => `<div />`. HorizonPanel, FlowPanel, VerticalPanel also give out only `<div />`.

Does any one know a solution?

Comment: You read the reasoning for using divs over other tags in HTMLPanel's javadocs for the `public HTMLPanel(String tag, String html)` ctor: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.java#69. In short: it's to please IE :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:HTMLPanel tag="span">
        <!-- your stuff -->
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Problem is you can't change the content via a ui:field with this technique.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep using a `<div>` but just add `display: inline` to its CSS, which will make it display as though it were a `<span>`.

Edit: fixed place at the end where I said 'div' but meant 'span'.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the answer above by Robert (sorry I can't figure out how to comment that directly)

This won't work out of the box, as widgets can't be placed inside plain HTML (the compiler will give you "error: found widget in html context"). But there's a simple workaround:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <span>
      <!-- Your content with widgets goes here -->
    </span>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

One other useful thing to mention is InlineHTML and InlineLabel widgets capable of holding arbitary html or plain text respectively in a <span>

Comment: I tried Bob's solution and it worked fine with widgets in the HTMLPanel.

Comment: my comment applies to an older GWT version - the one that was available in '10