# Defining optional parameters of a widget with UIbinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

The answer to the following question shows this is possible:

[Trying to get UIBinder to give me a span not a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257924/trying-to-get-uibinder-to-give-me-a-span-not-a-div)

If you declare `<g:HTMLPanel tag="span">` in the template, then the HTMLPanel will be a `<span>` element in the final result, instead of the default `<div>`.

The HTMLPanel has this constructor:

```
public HTMLPanel(String tag, String html)
```

which is probably called by this method, but how? If there is no tag attribute in the template, then the constructor used is probably this one:

```
public HTMLPanel(String html)
```

I understand that it is possible to annotate a Constructor with `@UiConstructor` to create a widget with parameters defined in the template, but how is it possible to change constructors depending on which attributes are defined?

And also, how is the `String html` filled automatically? Would there be some implicit definition of an html attribute as the content of the element? Or is this a nonstandard behavior of UIBinder just for HTMLPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLPanel` has a dedicated `HTMLPanelParser` that processes the element from the `ui.xml`.

Element parsers are an internal part of UiBinder, you cannot [add your own](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4461).

You have to declare a single `@UiConstructor` constructor and have the rest taken care of by setters, with some final *validation* possibly done in `onAttach` (similar to how `Composite` throws at attach-time when you forgot to call `initWidget`, and similarly for `Widget` and `setElement`).

In complex cases, and/or if you want to enforce the use of constructor arguments, then don't do anything special and have users of the widget use a `@UiFactory` or `@UiField(provided = true)`. This is already the case for `SuggestBox`, `ValueListBox` or `CellList` for instance.

My personal preference goes to that last approach.